# Dynamic Textboxes losing their values on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, webforms, dynamic-controls

I'm creating a web app in ASP.NET (web forms) and there's a part where I have to generate dynamic textboxes, I am able to do that but values I entered in textboxes disappears after button click. I have read many solutions on community but it does not work for me.

Here's my code of aspx

```
  <asp:Panel ID="pnlTextBoxes" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add New" OnClick="btnAddTextBox_Click" />
  <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Remove TextBox" OnClick="btnRemoveTextBox_Click" />
```

Here's code of code behind

```
protected void btnAddTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int controlsCount = (int)(ViewState["ControlsCount"] ?? 0);
    controlsCount++;
    ViewState["ControlsCount"] = controlsCount;
    GenerateControls(controlsCount);
}

protected void btnRemoveTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int controlsCount = (int)(ViewState["ControlsCount"] ?? 0);
    if (controlsCount > 0)
    {
        controlsCount--;
        ViewState["ControlsCount"] = controlsCount;
        GenerateControls(controlsCount);
    }
}
string[] baseIds = new string[] { "DSrNo", "DDescShBx", "DTtlBx", "DBNo", "DExpDt", "DHsnCd", "DTtlQty", "DRteUsd", "DAmtUsd" };
private void GenerateControls(int controlsCount)
{
    string[] labelTexts = new string[] { "Sr No.", "Desc. of Shipper Box", "Total Box", "Batch No", "Exp Date", "HSN Code", "Total qty",
        "Rate in Usd", "Amount in USD" };

    string[] colClasses = new string[] { "col-12 col-lg-1 mb-3", "col-12 col-lg-2 mb-3", "col-12 col-lg-1 mb-3", "col-12 col-lg-1 mb-3",
        "col-12 col-lg-1 mb-3", "col-12 col-lg-1 mb-3", "col-12 col-lg-1 mb-3", "col-12 col-lg-2 mb-3", "col-12 col-lg-2 mb-3" };
    if (pnlTextBoxes == null)
    {
        pnlTextBoxes = new Panel();
      
    }
  
    for (int i = 0; i < controlsCount; i++)
    {
        Panel row = new Panel();
        row.CssClass = "row";
      

        for (int j = 0; j < baseIds.Length; j++)
        {
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.ID = $"{baseIds[j]}_{i}";
            txt.CssClass = "form-control";
            EnableViewState=true;
          
        
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = labelTexts[j % labelTexts.Length]; 
            lbl.ID = $"lbl{baseIds[j]}_{i}";

            Panel col = new Panel();
            col.CssClass = "col-12 col-lg-" + colClasses[j % colClasses.Length]; 
            col.Controls.Add(lbl);
            col.Controls.Add(txt);

            row.Controls.Add(col);
        }
       


        pnlTextBoxes.Controls.Add(row);
    }
}
```

When user click on add text box button it add nine textboxes and on remove button it removes textboxes, But if I enter any value in textbox values entered in textboxes gets erased. It does not maintain its value to postback.

Comment: You don't need to be in `Page_Init` in 99.999% of the time, always use `Page_Load`

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! 

I would suggest to open up the Network tab in Developer Console in your browser (F12) and see what happens when you click the buttons. You say also that the text inside the buttons dissapears as soon as you click them. You might consider also adding asp hidden fields to maintain client state between postbacks. That means adding hidden fields to  pnlTextBoxes.Controls above inside method inside GenerateControls. 

Please check your grammar a bit too, sentences should start with capitalized letter and end with punctuation.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest to open up the Network tab in Developer Console in your browser (F12) and see what happens when you click the buttons. You say also that the text inside the buttons dissapears as soon as you click them. You might consider also adding asp hidden fields to maintain client state between postbacks. That means adding hidden fields to pnlTextBoxes.Controls above inside method inside GenerateControls. Please check your grammar a bit too, sentences should start with capitalized letter and end with punctuation.

Comment: @ToreAurstad
 Thank you for pointing out my grammatical mistakes. I did checked  Network tag in Developer consol , However there were too much information and I doesn't know which specific part to look for n But here's general info . There is multiple bar (Waterfall) Main bar I see is in my Page.aspx, Under Header Page.aspx there are this info available like Request Method: POST....  , Under Payload section I can see all controls I have ,View State value , And in controls  I can see value that  have entered in text box and got disappeared if there is more info to look out please tell me.